# facebook like get new error from today

Tags: php, facebook

When I click "like", a confirm button comes and when I click like in the new popup window that comes up, I am redirected to https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/like/confirm

I have all meta tag including fb:app_id.

It was correct till yesterday. and I get this error from today.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<fb:like href="my url" send="false" layout="button_count" width="30" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

I check this url with facebook debugger, but its perfect.

Comment: It's a problem in some countries, use iframe.

Comment: is it possible to use iframe in a single page more than one time?

Comment: @Mihai Iorga I got the same error when I use iframe. S, what should I do now? Please help me out.

Comment: I believe it's from your country, I get no error on my website.

Comment: there is no solutions? if you don't mind will you test this link from your side? http://insurancereviewboard.com/consumers/agentProfile/tuttiwala1234 and like . please...

Comment: It seems like Facebook is about (or has already done?) to introduce a filter algorithm that detects fake likes. Maybe you're affected for some reason. https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/improvements-to-our-site-integrity-systems/10151005934870766

Comment: @Daniel I test this from last few days, but only today I got this error. should I wait for few times and test this again?

Comment: @Moumita Dunno, I'd suggest to try contacting facebook directly. Maybe you're lucky and get a response...

Comment: @Daniel will you tell me the way to contact?

Comment: LikeBox is shown from my side

Comment: @Mihai Iorga wao thats great, that means its not my coding problem. thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, these days it seems there are some problems in some countries with displaying the `like` box.

Don't panic as the `like` box ca be seen from other countries.

Just checked your website and it seems to be just fine.

Comment: its been 2 hrs over. but still I didn't get any solutions.